How to get the result of command in WIX?
I have run a command or script in WIX, how can I obtain its running results or output?
After running a command or script, only whether it has been successfully executed can be obtained， can not set the resulr to a property.
I want to use commands or scripts to check if the current installation environment of the Installer is Win10 or above.
    <Binary Id="OSMajorVersionScript" SourceFile="test.bat" />

    <CustomAction Id="GetWindowsMajorVersion" 
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Property="WindowsMajorVersion"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="yes"
                  BinaryKey="OSMajorVersionScript"
                  DllEntry="WixShellExec"/>

Hope someone can answer my question. Thank you very much

You need to write a DLL CustomAction that is provided a Session object which can set a Property. You can't do it from an Exe based CustomAction.

Thanks a lot for your reply, I know how to do now.

Great. Please accept the answer and click the up arrow if it was helpful.
